# Destroy Oracle PLSQL Object

Tags: oracle, object, plsql, record, destroy

Is there a way to destroy a PL/SQL object, say, a record?

In visual pascal, we can use FreeAndNil(object), and this procedure releases the memory used by the object and points it to Nil (null), thus destroying the object.

I was wondering if there's a way to do that on PLSQL object/record, or if I should assign null to it.

Comment: The memory will be freed up when the variable goes out of scope.  Unless you are doing something pretty unusual, the amount of memory that would be consumed by a record (or any set of local variables) is pretty trivial and those variables exist in memory for a rather short period of time so it doesn't generally make sense to worry about that memory consumption.  Are you doing something that causes you to be concerned about the memory used by your local variables?

Comment: Yes. We have created a few packages that implement business rules. These packages make calculations and pass around records as parameters. While debugging, we ran into a case where on the first pass, no value was returned. Then, on the second pass, we got a normal return. While investigating the issue, we found out that the record filled with data from another method on the client app that used the same package. That's why I'm asking for a way to securely clear the record, so that we don't get mixed data. That behavior was unexpected.

Comment: That's a *very* different question from the one you're asking.  It is not possible for a PL/SQL object created in one session to be visible in another session.  If you have built a three-tier application where the middle tier maintains a connection pool and you have built packages that maintain state, you would want to clear package state as part of closing the logical connection and returning it to the pool.  If your packages are not stateful, I'd wager that your code has a bug.

Comment: @JustinCave it's a delphi desktop ERP that keeps some of it's business logic in PLSQL packages. A transaction is started when the app starts and it ends when it finishes. I know that this isn't the best approach, but nonetheless this is legacy software. Since it's the same transaction, me and my colleagues suspect that since we didn't explicitly destroyed the object after it's use, the data remained there.

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense.  Each session has its own transaction.  And it seems highly unlikely that an ERP application would be designed so that users can't see changes that others have made until the application exits.  Even then, however, transaction scope has nothing whatsoever to do with the scope of a PL/SQL variable.  A rollback doesn't revert the state of a PL/SQL variable, for example.

Comment: @JustinCave, this ERP is composed of more than one thousand independent programs. Each one is a separated piece of software that acts together on the same database. I know this might sound strange, but we are talking about software made more than 12 years ago. Anyway, this specific program is made for making sales orders. When you start a sale order, a transaction is opened. When you finish it, the transaction is commited and therefore closed. I'm saying that just to clarify on the ERP design bit. In regard to the PL/SQL scope, this has been clarified and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a row type to `null`, no problem.

This compiles fine:

```
declare
  r dual%rowtype;
begin
  r := null;
end;
```

If a variables looses scope (so after `end;` here), Oracle will automatically destroy it, so there is no need to set it to `null`, or deallocate it in any way.

Comment: I don't think that answers the OP's question (which - as far as I understand it - boils down to *whether you're required to or should* set it to NULL).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: I got your point. Better now? Added a final line of explanation.

Comment: Darn. That makes my answer obsolete - deleting it :-)

Comment: This sort of thing is how cargo-cult programming starts.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp that's not the point. Read my previous comment to see why I'm asking this.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt it's a mix between those two. I want to know if I need to do that, and if I have to, how to do it. In my previous response to JustinCave I've tried to explain why. Thanks for your answer. Thank you PatrickHofman as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the package had an global variable (a variable declared in the spec of the package).

The client application started a transaction that executed a function from this package; this function changed the global variable value. Then, another function, that relied on the variable value, was called. This led to the problem.

The conclusion is obvious: don't use global variables.

There's, of course, other solutions, like closing the transaction (thus destroying the variable like Patrick Hofman explained).

Like I said, this is legacy software... I refactored the code and this problem (along with a few others) is gone. Thanks for the help!